# Creating counts based on date ranges with inner join

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[Here is an illustration for what I'd like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxN0V.jpg)
Table A:

```
user_id | industry | startdate | enddate | generation
1          retail    2000-01-01 2001-01-01 Gen X
1          retail    2002-01-01 2003-02-01 Gen X
2          Tech      2001-01-01 2002-01-01 Gen X
2          Business  2002-03-01 2003-01-01 Gen X
2          Tech      2003-02-01 null       Gen X
...       ...       ...         ...         ...
35642     Medicine  2020-02-01  2022-03-01  Gen Z
```

Table B

```
month
1990-01-01
1990-02-01
...
2022-03-01
```

Desired Result:

```
industry | generation| count | month
retail      Gen X     200      2002-02-01
retail      Gen Y     250      2002-02-01
Tech        Gen X     130      2002-02-01
Tech        Gen Y     166      2002-02-01
...
```

For now, I've only got tables A and B. I want to create counts by industry, by month, by generation, but I'm not sure how I can do this using the two tables that I have.

My (incorrect) approach would be something like select count(*), industry, month, generation where A.startdate < B.month and A.enddate > B.month, but this query is obviously not running. Is what I want to do possible with just tables A and B?

Apologies if I'm being unclear, I am admittedly new to SQL queries and am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Can you put the image content in text such that the data can be copy pasted?
Can you format your question and put code in code blocks?

Comment: Sorry about that, Bert. I've updated my post!

Comment: Do you want counts just for the data that exists in table A or do you want counts for all possible combinations of month/industry/generation - with zeros where there is no data fir that combination in table A?

Comment: @NickW Preferably, the latter--I'd like counts by industry, by generation, by month, with zeros where there is no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing the steps of NickW gives me.
I guess that users whose enddate is null are still in businss

```sql
## Create tables
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    user_id int,
    industry text,
    startdate date,
    enddate date,
    generation text
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    month date
);

# Insert data
WITH series_months AS (
SELECT date(i) 
    from generate_series(
        date '1999-01-01', 
        date '2012-09-01',
        INTERVAL '1 month'
    ) i
)
INSERT INTO table_b (month)
SELECT * FROM series_months;


INSERT INTO table_a (user_id, industry, startdate, enddate, generation)
VALUES 
(1, 'retail', '2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', 'Gen X'),
(1, 'retail', '2002-01-01', '2003-02-01', 'Gen X'),
(2, 'Tech', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', 'Gen X'),
(2, 'Business', '2002-03-01', '2003-01-01', 'Gen X'),
(2, 'Tech', '2003-02-01', NULL, 'Gen X');

# Perform joins
WITH industry_generation as (
    SELECT distinct industry, generation from table_a
), months_industry_generation as (
 SELECT  *
   FROM table_b, industry_generation
), combined_table AS (
    SELECT mig.month, mig.industry, mig.generation, user_id, startdate, enddate
    FROM
        (SELECT * FROM months_industry_generation) mig
        inner join table_a a
    on mig.industry = a.industry AND mig.generation = a.generation
    where month >= startdate AND (month <= enddate OR enddate is null)
)
SELECT industry, generation, count(user_id) AS count, month
FROM combined_table
GROUP BY month, industry, generation
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4
;
```

[image: query results]

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

1. Create a CTE that generates the distinct list of industry/generation by querying table A
2. Create a 2nd CTE that cartesian joins the first CTE to table B - giving you a list of all months/industry/generation
3. Left outer join table A to the 2nd CTE and query for the result you want to achieve

Comment: Admittedly I don't fully grasp how to use CTEs, but I just wanted to make sure I understand the roadmap so to speak...
For step 1, I want to create a table with all generation/industry combinations.

Then, for step 2, cartesian/cross join that table with table B.

Finally, for step 3, join table A to table made in step 2, and it would be in this step where I create counts by industry/generation/month. Is that correct?